# sqlalchemy session to create or update records with * to many relationships

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a fairly simple flask app connected to a postgresql database. I am mainly using the flask app with [flask-admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so that I can add records to the database and perhaps build it out into a dashboard later. It's an internal use catalog, basically.

What I am trying to do is also write a script that connects to a third party API to add/update records in the database, so it does not got through the flask app. I am using SQLAlchemy to do this because it's consistent with the app and I just need something to work without fussing over SQL statements.

The flask app's data model is defined as such:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from flask_admin import Admin

# ... APPLICATION CONFIGURATION ...

# db Models

## Table for many to many
keywords = db.Table('keywords',
    db.Column('keyword_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('keyword.id')),
    db.Column('dataset_id', db.String(24), db.ForeignKey('dataset.dataset_id')),
)

## Model classes
class Dataset(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    dataset_id = db.Column(db.String(24), primary_key=True, unique=True)

    #relationships
    dataset_documentation = db.relationship('DataDocument', backref='dataset', lazy='dynamic')
    keywords = db.relationship('Keyword', secondary=keywords, backref='dataset', lazy='dynamic')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Keyword(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword

class DataDocument(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    document = db.Column(db.String(120))
    dataset_id = db.Column(db.String(24), db.ForeignKey('dataset.dataset_id'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document

# ... APPLICATION VIEWS ...
```

So we have `datasets` with some basic metadata and they have a one to many relationship with a filepath to a document and a many to many relationship to any number of keywords.

The separate script is connecting directly to the database, and mapping existing tables to objects that I can use to create a session and modify the database.

**script.py**

```
import config #local config only
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker


# Connecting to postgres database and creating a session with database objects, intantiate empty classes to populate
class Dataset(object):
    pass

class DataDocument(object):
    pass

class Keyword(object):
    pass

## How to instantiate the MTM association table?

db_uri = config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
meta = MetaData(engine)
dataset_table = Table('dataset', meta, autoload=True) #correct
datadocument_table = Table('dataset', meta, autoload=True) #incorrect?
keyword_table = Table('keyword', meta, autoload=True) #incorrect?
mapper(Dataset, dataset_table) #correct
mapper(DataDocument, datadocument_table, meta, autoload=True) #??
mapper(Keyword, keyword_table, meta, autoload=True) #??

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
# sample update

data_upsert = Dataset()
data_upsert.title = "Some title"
data_upsert.dataset_id = "Uniq_ID-123"
data_upsert.description = "lorem ipsum foo bar foo"

session.merge(data_upsert)

#attempt to add related properties

key1 = Keyword('test1')
key2 = Keyword('test2')
datadoc = DataDocument('path/to/document.txt')

# FAIL.

data_upsert.append(key1)
data_upsert.append(key2)
data_upsert.append(datadoc)

session.flush()
```

I am a newbie with sqlalchemy and I can just barely wrap my head around creating the `Dataset` object in the script from the database engine. But I was thinking in loading the `Keyword` and `Datadocument` tables as well that it would already understand the relationships based on what it is loading from the database, but this is where my understanding is running thin.

Is there a straightforward way to complete the picture here? I am assuming it doesn't make sense to define my models again explicitly in `script.py`, but in reviewing documentation and some tutorials, I am not seeing the missing pieces of loading these relationships into the session so that I can ingest all of the data into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your model definitions to add constructor functions. In that case, it allows you to pass the parameters to the object upon instantiation.

models.py

```
## Model classes
class Dataset(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    dataset_id = db.Column(db.String(24), primary_key=True, unique=True)

    #relationships
    dataset_documentation = db.relationship('DataDocument', backref='dataset', lazy='dynamic')
    keywords = db.relationship('Keyword', secondary=keywords, backref='dataset', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, title=None, desc=None, dataset_id=None):
        self.title = title
        self.description = desc
        self.dataset_id = dataset_id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Keyword(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, keyword=None):
        self.keyword = keyword

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keyword


class DataDocument(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    document = db.Column(db.String(120))
    dataset_id = db.Column(db.String(24), db.ForeignKey('dataset.dataset_id'))

    def __init__(self, document, dataset_id):
        self.document = document
        self.dataset_id = dataset_id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document
```

No need to define the model classes again in the script.py. You can simply import the classes you want to use from the models.py. Then you can insert the data object with its related objects altogether into the database in this way:

script.py

```
import config  #local config only
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from models import Dataset, DataDocument, Keyword


def loadSession(engine):
    """"""
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session


engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=False)
Base = declarative_base(engine)
# load session
session = loadSession(engine)
data_upsert = Dataset(title="Some title", dataset_id="Uniq_ID-125", desc="lorem ipsum foo bar foo")

# add related properties here
key1 = Keyword('test1')
key2 = Keyword('test2')
datadoc = DataDocument('path/to/document.txt', dataset_id="Uniq_ID-125")

# append the properties to the object 
data_upsert.dataset_documentation.append(datadoc)
data_upsert.keywords.append(key1)
data_upsert.keywords.append(key2)

session.add(data_upsert)

session.commit()
```

I've tested the code locally and hope it works for you.